# Continuing numbering from heading to list in toctree

Tags: python-sphinx, sections, toctree

I'm looking to get list numbers to continue on from heading numbers. I've tried the `:numbered:` directive in `.. toctree:`, but that only produces numbers for the headings.

For example:

```
Section
=====

Sub Section
-----------

#. item 1
#. item 2

  #. item 3
```

Which would generate:

## `1. Section`

### `1.1 Sub Section`

`1.1.1 Item 1`

`1.1.2 Item 2`

`1.1.2.1 Item 3`

What (if any) would be the approach to producing this result?

Comment: I don't think this is possible :(